# Activity Indicator - see if you participated in a Q&A at a glance

Tags: script, questions, comments, answers

### About

Activity Indicator is a userscript that displays a, well, indicator and some useful stats about your interactions with a given post. Inspired by [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411440/11407695), upon opening a post, the script adds a "participation" breakdown to where one finds Q&A stats normally:

[image: stats element with the breakdown added]

Due to the limited space, the labels are added in an abbreviated form but I hope they are intuitive enough but have full-text hints displayed on hover (since 1.2.0):

| Abbreviation | Stats |
| --- | --- |
| `A` | answered the question |
| `Q` | asked the question |
| `EA` | edited* an answer |
| `EQ` | edited* the question |
| `AC` | left a comment on one of the answers |
| `QC` | left a comment on the question |

* Currently limited to being the *latest editor* of a post but I intend to switch that to full post history analysis in the near future.

---

Here is a live preview of how label hints and jumping to action look like:

[image: hints and jumping to action preview]

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/activity-indicator/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/activity-indicator/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

The script *doesn't need* a userscript manager to work (but includes necessary headers).

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 93.0.4577.63 | ✔ 78.0.4093.184 | ✔ 92.0 | ✔ 93.0.961.38 | no |

### Change log

| Version | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2.0 | Enhanced stats labels with links to latest relevant post/comment and full-text hints on hover |
| 1.2.1 | Added meta sites of the Stack Exchange network to `@match` headers |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/activity-indicator/issues)

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/activity-indicator/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Uses [type definitions](https://stackapps.com/q/9063/78873) for Stack Exchange global objects.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/activity-indicator/pulls).

Comment: Is there any way to search posts where you have (or haven’t) done one (or more) of these activities?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica sorry, your comment went completely under my radar - not in the current version, but it is certainly possible as the info is already fetched, I can make each label a link that takes you to the respective post or comment :) If you want, you can make it a feature request by adding an answer here so as you are notified about the progress ( and some unicorn points for a cool suggestion too :) )

Answer (score 4):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Just a simple recommendation (I do not particularly like the abbreviations):

could there be a table on hover, e.g:

[image: table preview from Roomba Forecaster]

<sub>* Like the [Roomba Forecaster](https://stackapps.com/questions/7239/roomba-forecaster-when-will-the-question-be-roombaed-if-it-wont-why) userscript.</sub>

The table can contain long details like "Answered the question", "Edited the question", etc.

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Please add a way to search through these posts<sup>1</sup>.

Possible use cases:

- Checking your recent comments (on either questions or answers) to see whether they are still up to date.
- Checking whether or not some edits you made a while ago can be improved upon.
- If you normally comment on (or edit) posts that you've seen, you can use this to see if there are any semi-recent posts that you've missed (only useful on smaller sites)

---

<sub>1: by this I mean both a way to look at all the posts where you have taken a specific action and a way to look at all the posts where you haven't taken that action</sub>

Comment: most likely will not have time to work on userscripts until the election on SO ends (bots require too much attention) - but apart from that, can you elaborate on the "search" functionality a little bit? Currently, the latest version allows one to jump to their respective action by clicking on a label - searching is definitely blocked by adding a full-scale search for when one's action on a post is not the "latest" action, thus it would be nice to know more details about what you have in mind

Answer (score 0):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

A couple of minor change requests:

1. If the indicators include `Q` and `A` (i.e., on self-answered questions), it's more intuitive to show `Q` before `A`. (perhaps that should also happen with `EQ` &`EA` and `QC` &`AC`?)
2. I don't think `EQ` should show up when I'm the OP. Similarly, there's no need to show `EA` if I'm the author of that specific answer. Obviously, it should still show up if I have edited another (competing) answer.

To illustrate, on a self-answered question of mine, I currently see this:

[image: Current: A Q EA EQ AC QC]

I think it should show this instead:

[image: Desired: Q A QC AC]